# Error while opening a OPOS device

Tags: c#, .net, opos

I am using OPOS drivers for .net to access some POS peripherals. I have added the LDN using SetupPOS utiltiy. 
But when i try to open (Open command) the device , i am getting the an error.

**Message:"Configuration Information Error"**

Since i have added the LDN and the object initialization is happening. Error occuring while trying to open the device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OPOS devices typically store device-specific configuration information under a registry key something like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ServiceOPOS\<deviceType>\<deviceName>
```

Sometimes device manufacturers (e.g. Epson) provide a utility to update the configuration in the registry; sometimes not, and you have to do it manually.

From the error message I assume there is some problem with the configuration - if you can't work it out yourself, provide more details of the device in question and maybe post the content of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OLEforRetail\ registry key.

Comment: The information about the logical device name is available i Configuration.xml file . Is this xml and registry key both refers to the same data?..

Comment: and the error is not coming always.. very occassionly it comes.